# Problem with overpriced ESTA from ESTASERVICE.COM

Tags: esta

I just got charged $88 for an ESTA using a non-standard site.

Has anyone got any ideas as to whether I can get a refund?

Comment: I doubt it. You accepted the cost when you bought, now you're bound to it.

Comment: If you used a credit card (hopefully AMEX) you can dispute it. AMEX always takes my side in a dispute with merchants, ALWAYS

Comment: If you found the site in Google Search, you may notify Google to remove the link. Finally this week (after a lot of year) Google started to took action (and it ask people to notify such sites)

Comment: As noted in the linked Q&A you can dispute the charge with your card issuer _if they did not actually send in your ESTA application_.

Answer (score 7):

As you learn't the hard way, [esta.cbp.dhs.gov](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) is the only website where you should apply and pay for an ESTA application.

I don't think you can get your money back unfortunately.